# DataAdapter.Fill is slower in SQLite than SQL Server

Tags: sqlite

I trying to load about 100k rows from SQLite database into a datatable. The `Fill` method requires about 2 seconds for the entire operation. I noticed that doing the same operation with SQL Server 2014 takes only 0,7 secs!

This is my code:

```
SQLiteDataAdapter adpt= new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM myTable", sqliteCn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adpt.Fill(dt);
```

The table has 9 columns, 1 primary key and 1 unique index.

Is SQLite truly slower than SQL Server? If no, there are some specific operations to speed up this query?

Comment: You can try the "usual suspects": **(1)** avoid using `SELECT *` - define the list of columns explicitly, and retrieve **only** those columns that you **really** need; **(2)** add a `WHERE` clause to avoid loading the entire table - but only as many rows as you can easily handle at once

Comment: Check SQLite [FAQ - 19](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19)

Comment: @marc_s: My question was only to know why is there this difference between SQLite and SQLServer. Before this test I thinked that first was more faster than second. So, I'd like to know if there is some tuning operation to optimize SQLite that should I do.